# Multiple levels of .htaccess files with RewriteRule, only deepest level processed

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I have .htaccess files at multiple levels of a directory heirarchy, each with RewriteRules in them. However, when arequest is made for a file in a subdirectory, only the rules in the most deeply nested .htaccess file (up to the level of the requested file) are ever processed. Even having only a single line with "RewriteEngine On" is a subdirectory is enough to "disable" all rewrites defined in higher directories. This happens both for apache and litespeed httpd.

I had expected (and can't find any information otherwise) that all the RewriteRules would be combined into a single ruleset (presumably with deeper levels being processed last). However this doesn't seem to be happening.

Quite confused :) What am I not understanding?

Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set `RewriteOptions Inherit` in each `.htaccess`?

> In per-directory context this means
>   that conditions and rules of the
>   parent directory's .htaccess
>   configuration are inherited. Rules
>   inherited from the parent scope are
>   applied after rules specified in the
>   child scope.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help, I had mistakenly thought that that only inherited "options," such as RewriteBase etc... as I had tried it but it wasn't working, I think due to some [L] flags (also though parent rules were applied first!). At any rate inheriting options in this way seems a bit limited, as it (for me at least) strips the _current_ directories prefix (i.e. not that of the parent directory), and also keeps adding the path-info from the _initial_ request URI (not the current state of the substitution). Is this the only mechanism for combining RewriteRules across multiple directories?